# Write programs that read a line of input as a string and print every second letter of the string in Python

Tags: python

Write programs that read a line of input as a string and print every second letter of the string in Python?

So far I have written:

```
string=input('Enter String: ')

for char in range(0,len(string),2):

    print(len(char))
```

if i input a string: `qwerty`
it should print "`qet`"

Comment: Why are you printing the length of the character (which will always be 1)?

Comment: What *does* it print instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep it much simpler than this. If you enter a word and are looking to slice it at a specific point, use slicing.

Your criteria: `qwerty it should print "qet"`

So, you are looking to print every second letter:

```
>>> a = "querty"
>>> a[::2]
'qet'
```

Slicing works like this:

```
[from start: from end: step]
```

So, in your case, you are looking to simply print every second, so you want to make use of your `step`. So, simply slice leaving the `start` and `end` empty, since you want to position yourself at the beginning of the string and then simply go every second. This is the reasoning behind using `[::2]`

Answer (score 0):

Every second letter should start with index of 1 not 0. So, if your input is "qwerty", you output should be "wry".

Code below may be able to answer your question.

```
sentence = input("\nPlease enter a string : ")
print("Every second letter of the string " + sentence + " is ", end="")

for i in range(len(sentence)):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        print(sentence[i] + " ", end="")
```